# How to transform a nested C++11 bind expression

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, bind, compile-time

Is it possible to transform a nested C++11 bind expression? For example, in the code below, the bind expression associated with `f` will first multiply its argument by two, before adding one to the result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{                                                                               
  auto add1 = [](int x) { return x+1; };
  auto mul2 = [](int x) { return x*2; };

  auto f = std::bind(add1, std::bind(mul2, _1));
  std::cout << f(0) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Could we create a transformed version of `f` which instead *first* adds one, *then* multiplies the result by two; the result would behave as if defined as:

```
auto f2 = std::bind(mul2, std::bind(add1, _1));
```

This example is simplified by the fact that it's structure is analogous to a list; whereas a bind expression is more generally a tree.

Comment: What's the use of that? You can't generally reverse the composition (totally ignoring bind here) and you also have no knowledge of the internals of `bind`.

Comment: @Xeo a functional approach probably, but if the OP loves being functional, there is not too much support for it under C++ I think, or at least C++ it's not a real functional language.

Comment: @Xeo I don't in general want to reverse the composition. This is merely a simple example. I want to explore the possibilities for transforming bind expressions. I might select a subtree; or an individual function object from an aggregate structure. For now, I'll be happy with the reverse though. Thankyou.

Comment: The return value of `std::bind` is unspecified. You have to define your own compile-time tree in order to do what you want.

Comment: If you want to do stuff like this, check out Boost.Proto. It builds expression trees that can be walked and manipulated.

Answer (score 5):

`std::bind` is a black box. It does not support introspection (aside from `std::result_of` and `std::is_bind_expression`) or polymorphism (aside from `std::placeholders`). When you call `f(0)`, it compiles to native code for `0*2+1`.

Inside that black box is something like an expression template, referencing the composed functor types and providing storage for any bound arguments. Such implementation is tied to the compiler, and platform  details will in fact differ greatly.

If you want to portably manipulate expressions, check out the [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/proto.html) generalized expression template library. It's heavy stuff, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a brutal hack on VS2013, and is totally non-portable, but I was interested to see if I could make something work.  It probably doesn't solve your problem, but I thought it was worth sharing.  Because the return value of `std::bind` is implementation defined, portability is going to be a big roadblock on this problem.  There's also lots handwaving on most of the template deduction.

```
template<class A, class B, class C>
std::_Bind<false, void, B&, std::_Bind<false, void, A&, C>> 
inverse(std::_Bind<false, void, A&, std::_Bind<false, void, B&, C>> f) {
    A func_a;
    B func_b;
    return std::bind(func_b, std::bind(func_a, _1));
}

int main() {
    auto add1 = [](int x) { return x+1; };
    auto mul2 = [](int x) { return x*2; };

    auto f = std::bind(add1, std::bind(mul2, _1));
    std::cout << f(0) << '\n';

    auto g = inverse(f);
    std::cout << g(0) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. You're right about the portability: GCC 4.9 has no knowledge of your `std::_Bind`. Nevertheless, with a bit of work, I think the idea could be valid.

Comment: @user2023370 [It looks like its in there somehow](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01199_source.html#l01245) but it has a different signature. Your setup might also be hiding the libstdc++ implementation details with a switch or two.